# Difference between 居ます and 住む

Tags: word-choice

Cantonese / Chinese is my first language, where 居 and 住 both mean live in

Usually I would say

```
私は香港に住んでいます
```

But recently a japanese friend of mine says

```
今　京都に居ます
```

Are their meanings the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

住む - to live/reside in place
居る - to exist/to be (for living things)

> 私は香港に住んでいます
> I live in Hong Kong
>   
>   今　京都に居ます
> Now I am in Kyoto.

Why he is in Kyoto is not said, so that could mean that he is either living there or visiting. Looking in the [dictionary](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/15573/meaning/m0u/%E5%B1%85%E3%82%8B/) it does show 住む and 滞在する as definition  number 2.

Comment: then is います＝居ます?

Comment: @chenghopan Yes. いる -> 居る